# Convert String to Object for SpringMVC

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have some problems with converting String to Object in Spring MVC 3.0.1 framework. When I want to add some data (add new product) to the PostgreSQL database through form using custom web editor, no errors are displayed, form fields are inserted into database and only product category isn't inserted for product I add (In database in `category_types` I have inserted some categories and they show up in view). When I remove InitBinder method in Controller I got error that should appear that there are no editors to convert what I want.

Here is the code of my custom webeditor:

```
package Webeditors;
import java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport;
import Models.CategoryType;
public class CategoryTypeWebEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

@Override
public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException { 

    CategoryType a = new CategoryType(); 
    a.setId(Long.parseLong(text));
    setValue(a);  
}      

@Override
public String getAsText() {

    CategoryType type = (CategoryType) getValue();
    return type == null ? null :  Long.toString(type.getId());  
}
```

}

My **CategoryType** class is:

```
package Models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="category_types")
public class CategoryType {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
long id;

String name;

public CategoryType(){}

public CategoryType(long id, String name){

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;

}

...

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof CategoryType){
        CategoryType a = (CategoryType)obj;
    return a.getId() == id;
    }
    return false;
}   
}
```

In my JavaBeans **Product** I have declared:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
List<CategoryType> type;

public Product(){

    type = new ArrayList<CategoryType>();

}
...

public List<CategoryType> getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(List<CategoryType> type) {
    this.type = type;
}
```

In my **Controller** I have something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)

public String addProduct(Model model,
        @ModelAttribute("addproduct") Product product, BindingResult result){

....
}
@ModelAttribute("categorytypes")
public List<CategoryType> loadCategoryTypes() {
    List<CategoryType> types = dao.getCategory_Types();
    return types;
}
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(CategoryType.class, new CategoryTypeWebEditor());
}
```

and I am displaying it like that:

```
<form:form cssClass="form-horizontal" method="Post"
        action="addproductform.html" commandName="addproduct">
<form:checkboxes items="${categorytypes}" path="type" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" delimiter="<br>"/>
<form:errors cssStyle="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 160px;" cssClass="alert alert-error" element="div" path="type" />
</form:form>
```

Any idea what Am I doing wrong that it's not adding because I stuck with it..
Thanks

Comment: Well, could see an exact piece of code that is likely not to function as expected?

Comment: @Lion it's CategoryTypeWebEditor (my custom web editor) class causing some problems I assume

Comment: Does the method call `CategoryType type = (CategoryType) getValue();` inside the `getAsText()` method in the class `CategoryTypeWebEditor` really returns an object of type `CategoryType` and the method `type.getId()` really returns the correct id (a parsable value to the `java.lang.Long` type) and also the parameter to the method `setAsText(String text)` is being supplied? Otherwise there is nothing to see that might be wrong. Just try to trace it.

Comment: @Lion I tried to print `type.getId()` but method `public String getAsText()` doesn't print anything on my console when I want to print that id

Comment: Then you may need to check the external dependencies to make it return the correct id (besides the code in the question, what is returned by the method `getValue()`). Trace to see why is not being returned the correct value of id.

Comment: @Lion Ok it's returning correct id, the id is the same in set method and get method so no idea what is wrong

Comment: @Lion I have changed `itemValue="id"` to `itemValue="name"` in form view and I got error like this: `Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.List for property type; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "eBook"` it has something to it ?